# Contextual relative path reference in Assemble

Tags: assemble

Is there a way to set relative paths to assets in Assemble?  For example I have a single layout that references a css doc, eg.

```
assets/_css/myStyles.css
```

However I have some pages within sub directories that use this single layout, but the path reference for those pages would be

```
../assets/_css/myStyles.css
```

Is there a way to tell Assemble, get the path from the relative directory of the page?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [options.assets](http://assemble.io/docs/options-assets.html) setting.  It is a path defined in the Gruntfile like this:

```
assemble: {
    options: {
      assets: 'output/assets'
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in Handlebars templates to refer to your assets folder tree:

```
<script src="{{assets}}/js/theme.js"></script>
```

And Assemble will modify this path for pages in subdirectories correctly.